# SwiftU Document-based app error: "The document could not be opened"

Tags: swift, file, swiftui, ios16

I am building a document-based app with SwiftUI, but whenever I want to create a document in the app, the app shows an alert with the following title: "The document could not be opened"

I hit the same problem with Apple's sample project: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/building_a_document-based_app_with_swiftui

The interesting part is that I only get this error message when I am creating a new file from the "Recents" tab, but when I am creating it from the "Browse" tab, then it works.

The beta testers from my app are also experiencing this issue, and they use multiple types of OS versions, and they have enough storage to create the files.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced the very same problem on an iOS-only target. However, if I compile the same codebase as a multiplatform target and run it on iOS, the issue disappears.